# how to solve Cannot find module 'expo/bundledNativeModules.json'

Tags: reactjs

i have problem after  run expo strat

```js
Cannot find module 'expo/bundledNativeModules.json'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\s\Desktop\app\noop.js
```